# Ajax to insert multiple records from form inputs, add counter to hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've created a page that, based on an array from the database, creates multiple forms. Each form has an input with an 'add' button which dynamically adds new inputs (up to 10 inputs per form)

This works fine, but now I'm getting to where I want to submit andy input values added into the database. I have 2 main issues here:

1. The hidden input in my form `<input type="hidden" name="tickerID" id="tickerID" value="<?php echo $ticker['ticker'] ?>">` has a non unique ID, so no matter which form I submit from, it has the ticker value belonging to the first form only.
2. Once I have that value, and serialize with any filled inputs in that form, I call addticker.php to insert. I'm inserting the ticker id and the content from the form inputs, but I need to do this as a foreach I believe, because if 5 inputs were added and filled in, I need a record for each. All 5 would have the same ticker ID and the respective content from the input.

Any help is appreciated

```
<?php foreach($tickerDisplays as $key => $ticker):?>

    <form id="Items" method="post">
        <label id="ItemLabel">Item 1: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Items[]"><br/>
        <button type="button" class="moreItems_add">+</button>

        <input type="hidden" name="tickerID" id="tickerID" value="<?php echo $ticker['ticker'] ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="saveTickerItems" value="Save Ticker Items">  
    </form>

<?php endforeach;?>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("button.moreItems_add").on("click", function(e) {
var tickerID = $('#tickerID').val();
  var numItems = $("input[type='text']", $(this).closest("form")).length;
  if (numItems < 10) {
    var html = '<label class="ItemLabel">Item ' + (numItems + 1) + ': </label>';
    html += '<input type="text" name="Items[]"/><br/>';
    $(this).before(html);
    console.log(tickerID);
  }
});

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#Items").submit(function(e) {


//variables?

//var tickerID coming from <input type="hidden" name="tickerID" id="tickerID" value="<?php echo $ticker['ticker'] ?>">

//var Items[]

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: addticker.php,
       data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});

</script>
```

addticker.php

```
$tickerID = $_POST[''];
$content = $_POST[''];

$addTicker = "
    INSERT INTO tickerTable (tickerID, content)
    values ('$tickerID', '$content');
"
$mysqlConn->query($addTicker)
```

Comment: Can't repeat element ID's in a page. Use a class instead and look for that class instance inside the form instance. When multiple id's exist an id selector will only ever find the first one in page

Comment: So should I justuse a class and  add a counter in my JavaScript?

Comment: If you need that id from input can do something like `var tickerID = $(this).closest('form').find('.tickerIdClass').val()`

Comment: That worked, thanks so much!